# Get cells from last section uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have dynamically tableview with many section whitch is adding in run time by tap on button.

This button must send data from cells in last section (many type of custom cells).

How can i get cells or indexpath's of cells in last section?
I was trying to add these cells to array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but i use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to create this cells, so this is problematic.

Edit:
My code:

```
class ProcessViewController: UITableViewController, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate{

//this will be cell
struct field {
    var name, type, id, hint, output, specialType:String
    var selectOptions:NSMutableArray
    var settings:NSArray
}

struct group {
    var name:String
    var fields:[field]
}

// this will be sections
struct block {
    var groups:[group]
    var id, name:String
}

var blocks:[block] = []

//fields in last (active) block
//var fields:[field] = []

//array of cells with some input
var cellsInTable:NSMutableArray = []
var cellWithCustomHeight:[NSIndexPath] = []

@IBOutlet var sendFormButton: UIButton!

var jsonData:NSDictionary?
@IBOutlet var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var allfields:[field] = []
var numberOfOldCells = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 62/255.0, green: 80/255.0, blue: 178/255.0, alpha: 1);
    //print("json w srodku \(self.jsonData)")
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        self.revealViewController().delegate = self
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    //print(self.jsonData)

    let data = self.jsonData?.valueForKey("data") as! NSMutableDictionary

    //set title of the screen
    self.title = data.valueForKey("name") as? String

    //hide button if process is completed
    if(data.valueForKey("progress") as! Int == 1){
        sendFormButton.hidden = true
        //print("asdasd")
    }
    parseData(data)

    //print("Bloki: \(self.blocks)")

}

func parseData(data:NSMutableDictionary){
    self.cellsInTable = []
    //blocks is the sections in tableView, fields is a cells and groups (for now)
    let blocks = data.valueForKey("blocks") as! NSMutableArray
    self.blocks = []
    self.allfields = []

    blocks.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock {obj, i, stop in
        //print( obj.valueForKey("input"))
        var inputs:NSMutableArray = []

        //get inputs from current block, if input is only one it is dictionary in swift
        if let kinputs = obj.valueForKey("input") as? NSArray{
            inputs = NSMutableArray(array:kinputs)
        }else{
            inputs.addObject(obj.valueForKey("input")!)
        }

        inputs.removeLastObject()
        var outputs:NSArray = []
        if let koutputs = obj.valueForKey("output") as? NSArray{
            outputs = koutputs
        }
        //print("wrona \(outputs) kracze razy: \(outputs.count)")

        var tmpGroups:[group] = []

        //inupt is a group
        inputs.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({input, j, stop in
            //print("input w petli: \(input)")
            if(input.valueForKey("fields") != nil){
                let forms = NSMutableArray(array:input.valueForKey("fields") as! NSArray)

                var tmpFields:[field] = []
                let groupField:field = field(name:
                    input.valueForKey("name") as! String,
                    type: "group",
                    id: "0",
                    hint: input.valueForKey("name") as! String,
                    output: "",
                    specialType: "group",
                    selectOptions: [],
                    settings:[]
                )

                tmpFields.append(groupField)
                forms.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({fieldObj, k, stop in
                    let fromId = fieldObj.valueForKey("id") as! String

                    var output:String = ""

                    let tmpOutputs = outputs.valueForKey(fromId) as! NSArray

                    print(tmpOutputs)
                    print(output)

                    if tmpOutputs.count != 0{
                        if let _ = tmpOutputs[0] as? NSString{
                            output = tmpOutputs[0] as! String
                        }
                    } else {
                        //print(outputs.valueForKey(String(k)))
                    }

                    let selectOptions = NSMutableArray(array: fieldObj.valueForKey("selectOptions") as! NSArray)
                    //print("asdasdad\(fieldObj)")
                    let tmpField:field = field(
                        name: fieldObj.valueForKey("name") as! String,
                        type: fieldObj.valueForKey("type") as! String,
                        id: fromId,
                        hint: fieldObj.valueForKey("hint") as! String,
                        output:output,
                        specialType: fieldObj.valueForKey("specialType") as! String,
                        selectOptions: selectOptions,
                        settings:fieldObj.valueForKey("settings") as! NSArray
                    )
                    tmpFields.append(tmpField)
                })

                let tmpGroup:group = group(name: input.valueForKey("name") as! String, fields: tmpFields)
                tmpGroups.append(tmpGroup)
            }
        })

        let tmpBlock:block = block(groups: tmpGroups,
            id: obj.valueForKey("id") as! String,
            name: obj.valueForKey("name") as! String
        )

        self.blocks.append(tmpBlock)


    }

}


func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.blocks[section].name as String
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return blocks.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var formsInGroup:Int = 0;

    for group in self.blocks[section].groups{
        formsInGroup += group.fields.count
    }

    return formsInGroup
    //return blocks[section].fields.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(self.cellWithCustomHeight.contains(indexPath)){
        return CGFloat(132)
    } else {
        return CGFloat(47)
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //geting fields in current group
    self.allfields = []
    for group in self.blocks[indexPath.section].groups {
        self.allfields.appendContentsOf(group.fields)
    }

    print("bloki \(self.blocks.count), sekcje: \(indexPath.section)")



    //print(self.allfields.count)

    let cellType = self.allfields[indexPath.row].type as String


    //print("row: \(indexPath.row), sections: \(indexPath.section)")

    switch cellType {
        case "group":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("groupCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! groupCell
            cell.groupName.text = self.allfields[indexPath.row].name
            return cell
        case "text":
            if(self.allfields[indexPath.row].specialType == "date"){

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("datePickerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! datePickerCell
                cell.hint.text = self.allfields[indexPath.row].name as String

                let output = self.allfields[indexPath.row].output as String

                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

                self.cellWithCustomHeight.append(indexPath)

                if(output != ""){

                    print(self.allfields[indexPath.row].name)
                    //print( " output: \(output)")
                    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
                    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(self.allfields[indexPath.row].output)
                    cell.date.setDate(date!, animated: false)
                    cell.date.userInteractionEnabled = false

                }



                if !self.cellsInTable.containsObject(cell){
                    self.cellsInTable.addObject(cell)
                }
                setCellsToSend(indexPath.section)
                return cell

            }else{

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("textCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! textCell
                cell.hint.text = self.allfields[indexPath.row].name as String
                let output = self.allfields[indexPath.row].output as String
                cell.settings = self.allfields[indexPath.row].settings
                if self.allfields[indexPath.row].specialType == "number" {
                    cell.input.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
                }
                cell.input.text = ""
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
                if(output != ""){

                    //print(fields[indexPath.row].name)
                    //print(output)

                    cell.input.text = self.allfields[indexPath.row].output
                    cell.input.userInteractionEnabled = false
                }
                if !self.cellsInTable.containsObject(cell){
                    self.cellsInTable.addObject(cell)
                } else {
                        print("kuuuuuurwa \(self.allfields[indexPath.row].name)")
                }
                setCellsToSend(indexPath.section)
                return cell

            }
        case "checkbox":

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("checkBoxCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! checkBoxCell
            cell.selections = self.allfields[indexPath.row].selectOptions
            cell.hint.text = self.allfields[indexPath.row].name as String
            cell.settings = self.allfields[indexPath.row].settings
            cell.indexPath = indexPath
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

            if !self.cellsInTable.containsObject(cell){
                self.cellsInTable.addObject(cell)
            } else {
                print("kuuuuuurwa \(self.allfields[indexPath.row].name)")
            }
            setCellsToSend(indexPath.section)
            return cell
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("unknownCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "niezaimplementowany typ pola: \(cellType)"
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cell
    }

}

func setCellsToSend(sectionInTable:Int){
    if(sectionInTable == self.blocks.count-2){
        print("sekcja \(sectionInTable)")
        self.numberOfOldCells = self.cellsInTable.count
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "showCheckBox"){
        let checkBoxController = segue.destinationViewController as! CheckBoxController
        let cell = sender as! checkBoxCell

        //print(cell.settings)
        checkBoxController.selections = cell.selections
        checkBoxController.multiple = checkboxMultiValue(cell.settings)
        checkBoxController.indexPath = cell.indexPath
        checkBoxController.selected = cell.output
    }

}   

func checkboxMultiValue(settings:NSArray)->Bool{
    var boolToReturn:Bool = false

    settings.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({obj, i, end in
        if(obj.valueForKey("name") as! String == "multi_values"){
            if( obj.valueForKey("checked") as! String == "multi_values"){
                boolToReturn = true;
            }
        }
        //print(i)
    })

    return boolToReturn
}

@IBAction func saveSelectedSelections(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let checkBoxController = segue.sourceViewController as! CheckBoxController
    let selectedRowsPath = checkBoxController.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows

    var output:[String] = []
    if(selectedRowsPath?.count > 0){
        for rowPath in selectedRowsPath!{
            let cell = checkBoxController.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(rowPath) as! selectionCell
            output.append(cell.nameLabel.text! as String)

        }
    }
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(checkBoxController.indexPath!) as! checkBoxCell
    cell.output = output
}

@IBAction func sendForm(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("\(self.numberOfOldCells) i \(self.cellsInTable.count)")



    var postData:Dictionary<Int, AnyObject> = [:]
    var post = ""
    var iterator:Int = 0
    for var i = self.numberOfOldCells; i < self.cellsInTable.count; ++i{


        if let cellText = self.cellsInTable[i] as? textCell{
            //print("cellText \(cellText.input.text as String!)")

            postData[iterator] = cellText.input.text as AnyObject!

            post += "\(iterator):{'\(cellText.input.text! as String)'}&"
            iterator++


        } else if let cellCheckBox = self.cellsInTable[i] as? checkBoxCell{
            //print(cellCheckBox.output)
            let checkBoxOutput = cellCheckBox.output

            var data:String = ""

            for var i = 0; i < checkBoxOutput.count; ++i {
                if ( i == 0) {
                    data += checkBoxOutput[i]
                }else{
                    data += ";\(checkBoxOutput[i])"
                }
            }

            post += "\(iterator):{'\(data)'}&"
            postData[iterator] = data as AnyObject!
            //postData.append(data as String!)
            iterator++

        }else if let cellDate = self.cellsInTable[i] as? datePickerCell{
            //print(cellDate.date.date)
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
            let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(cellDate.date.date)

            postData[iterator] = date as AnyObject!

            post += "\(iterator):{'\(date)'}&"

            //postData.append(date as String!)
            iterator++
        }
    }
    //print("Post data:\(postData)")
    //getNewBlock(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(postData))
    print(post)
    getNewBlock(post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!)
}

func getNewBlock(postData:NSData){

    //print("Post data jako nsdata:\(postData)")

    //var blockId = "a"
    let blockId = blocks.last!.id

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://app.proces.io/Cloud/?Systems/Proces/Process/Block/makeAction/id-\(blockId)")!
    print(url)
    let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        urlData, response, error in
        var requestData: NSDictionary?
        do{
            requestData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as? NSDictionary

            //print(requestData)
            if ( requestData != nil ) {

                let success:NSInteger = requestData!.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

                if(success == 1)
                {
                    //print(self.blocks.count)
                    let data = requestData!.valueForKey("process") as! NSMutableDictionary
                    //print(self.allfields)
                    //self.numberOfOldCells = self.cellsInTable.count

                    //print(self.blocks)
                    self.allfields = []
                    self.parseData(data)
                    //print(self.blocks.count)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })

                } else {
                    print("cos poszlo nie tak \(requestData?.valueForKey("validation_errors")), values: \(requestData?.valueForKey("values"))")
                }

            }
        } catch let error as NSError{
            print("cos poszlo nie tak: \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Edit 2: minimal version with some explains:

```
    class ProcessViewController: UITableViewController, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate{
//this will be cell
struct field {
    var name, type, id, hint, output, specialType:String
    var selectOptions:NSMutableArray
    var settings:NSArray
}

struct group {
    var name:String
    var fields:[field]
}

// this will be sections
struct block {
    var groups:[group]
    var id, name:String
}

var blocks:[block] = []

var jsonData:NSDictionary?
@IBOutlet var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var allfields:[field] = []
var numberOfOldCells = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    parseData(data)
}

func parseData(data:NSMutableDictionary){
   //in this function i have a parsing data from json, whitch create me array of blocks (global variable "blocks")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.blocks[section].name as String
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return blocks.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var formsInGroup:Int = 0;

    for group in self.blocks[section].groups{
        formsInGroup += group.fields.count
    }

    return formsInGroup
    //return blocks[section].fields.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(self.cellWithCustomHeight.contains(indexPath)){
        return CGFloat(132)
    } else {
        return CGFloat(47)
    }
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //geting fields in current group
    self.allfields = []
    for group in self.blocks[indexPath.section].groups {
        self.allfields.appendContentsOf(group.fields)
    }

    let cellType = self.allfields[indexPath.row].type as String

    switch cellType {
        case "group":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("groupCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! groupCell
            cell.groupName.text = self.allfields[indexPath.row].name
            return cell
        case "text":
            if(self.allfields[indexPath.row].specialType == "date"){

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("datePickerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! datePickerCell
                cell.hint.text = self.allfields[indexPath.row].name as String

                let output = self.allfields[indexPath.row].output as String

                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

                self.cellWithCustomHeight.append(indexPath)

                if(output != ""){

                    print(self.allfields[indexPath.row].name)
                    //print( " output: \(output)")
                    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
                    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(self.allfields[indexPath.row].output)
                    cell.date.setDate(date!, animated: false)
                    cell.date.userInteractionEnabled = false

                }
                return cell

            }else{

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("textCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! textCell
                cell.hint.text = self.allfields[indexPath.row].name as String
                let output = self.allfields[indexPath.row].output as String
                cell.settings = self.allfields[indexPath.row].settings
                if self.allfields[indexPath.row].specialType == "number" {
                    cell.input.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
                }
                cell.input.text = ""
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
                if(output != ""){

                    cell.input.text = self.allfields[indexPath.row].output
                    cell.input.userInteractionEnabled = false
                }
                return cell

            }
        case "checkbox":

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("checkBoxCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! checkBoxCell
            cell.selections = self.allfields[indexPath.row].selectOptions
            cell.hint.text = self.allfields[indexPath.row].name as String
            cell.settings = self.allfields[indexPath.row].settings
            cell.indexPath = indexPath
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            return cell
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("unknownCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "niezaimplementowany typ pola: \(cellType)"
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cell
    }

}
@IBAction func sendForm(sender: AnyObject) {
    // in this function i must send data from cells in last section and add new section on the basis of request
}
```

Comment: In numberOfRowsInSection: method you could check for the last section, total cell count.

Comment: Not clear why you need the cell. Any data you need should come from the data model.

Comment: How are you adding data to the cells ? .. I mean are you using some NSArray variable ... because then you must be knowing what data was added and perhaps keep the index from which you are entering the information to the custom UITableviewCell

Comment: Show us the code you have now (all your tableview code) and a short stub of what you are trying to do. It is not clear what you are wanting. Maybe you are trying to find out what cell a particular button press came from?

Comment: in this uitableview i show many cells with diffrent inputs.
Before user tap on button i need sent data from cells in last section with post, and list one new secition with many cells generated from json and before next tap on button i need send this new section and over and over again

Comment: @PrzemekBartnik Please consider showing us a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've tried, and what you want to achieve. This will help people here at SO to help you. Given the huge lump of code you've posted above, many prospective answerers will simply not bother.

Comment: I think you need to learn some basic design patterns

Comment: yes, i do, this is beginning of my adventure with swift and ios